# Resampling air temperature gridded data to sub-grid resolution

Tags: qgis, r

I'd like to obtain a 30-m resolution gridded dataset of air temperature from the ~1km gridded data of WorldClim, of Hijmans et al., 2005) for a mountainous region.

The easiest procedure (I thought it was...), with any Raster calculator, is **T30m = T1km + (Z30m - Z1km)*lapse.rate**, but this produces a 30-m grid on which the footprint of the 1km grid is kind of superimposed (<del>[map here](https://bfs.ujf-grenoble.fr/files/e6a34f75567e06e282ebf0e4fc6b85be/30m_gridded_temperature_1kmfootprint.png)</del>: the colored cells "seem" to be at 1km but they are actually at 30m resolution, and you can see some small unexplained holes in the temperature raster)...

Does anyone have an idea to solve the problem, preferably with QGIS and/or R? <del>[Here](https://bfs.ujf-grenoble.fr/files/3ecbd9c9212cf0238e4e25e9868a6941/data.zip) is a sample of</del>  the input data I use (30-m ASTER DEM, 1km GLOBE DEM and 1km air temperature).